# Best practices using native queries for different databases

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

We have following setup:

- Spring with hibernate
- HsqlDb for development integration tests and Oracle in production

Now we would like to use table functions especially for variable IN lists in Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE ( cast(in_list('abc,xyz,012') as myTabletype)))
```

So we need to use a native query. The problem is though HsqlDb supports table functions, the query would look slightliy different.

I know we can use `query.setParameter(...)` in JPA QL with lists but this leads to bad query-cache. So are there any best practices to solve this problem?

Solutions which came to my mind:

1. Using temporary tables. Problem: impossible with readOnly-transactions
2. Mock entityManager and change query string.
3. Dinamically check for database dialect and switch query.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can have different implementations for your DAO specific to Oracle or Hypersonic.  Inject in the one appropriate for your environment.  A better idea would be to use Oracle throughout so you can develop and test with the database that will actually be used in production.  What good are those tests otherwise?

Comment: @duffymo How would I do that best for spring annotation based configuration? I would also need two implementations of services calling the DAO. You are right it would be more appropriate when using oracle througout and we did that already in another project. But it was slow ecspecially cause of data management before the tests. So we decided to use an in-memory-database.

Comment: Your configuration would be different for each environment.  I would figure out how to use Oracle all the way through.  Agile would suggest that every developer would have their own schema.